# Use two variables in a command - Solaris

Tags: solaris, command

I am trying to summary some information in Solaris CDom but get stack in a point. I have a xlsx file that have in a column a server name and in the other column a LUN id that is attach to that server. So the need is that I want to run this command:

```
ldm list -o disk | grep servername | grep -i lunid
```

But im not being capable of doing this, because the information must be read sequentially, for example:

```
server1 lunid1
server2 lunid2
server3 lunid3

ldm list -o disk | grep server1 | grep -i lunid1
```

and so on with the other server and lunid, always using the servers and lunid from the same line. (server2- lunid2 | server3 - lunid3 , etc)

Hope i was clear, and appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved doing this:
for lun in $(cat luns) ; do if [[ $(ldm list -o disk | grep -i $lun) || $(zpool status | grep -i $lun) ]];then echo "$lun: Still attach" ; else echo "$lun: succesfully removed" ; fi ; done